# Python chunk echos in r-markdown, but not r-notebook

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, reticulate, rnotebook

I like to take notes inside of r-notebooks and have recently been trying to incorporate python code chunks into some of my documents. I have no problems executing python chunks and displaying the output, but I get different behavior depending on whether I'm using an R-notebook or an R-markdown document. While R-markdown will echo the python code and display the output, R-notebook will only display the output. I have tried explicitly stating `echo=T` in the chunk, bit it does not change the outcome. Any thoughts on how to get the appropriate behavior in R-notebooks?

EDIT: Will also add that this behavior in notebooks only appears to happen when the code chunk has a printed output. A chunk that does not print will echo code correctly.

Below is an example:

**R-notebook example**

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

Example R-notebook

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(reticulate)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```
```{python}
print("Hello world")
```
````

[image: Output of R-notebook]

---

**R-markdown example**

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_document
---

Example R-notebook

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(reticulate)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```
```{python}
print("Hello world")
```
````

[image: Output of R-markdown]

Comment: Have you loaded the package `library(reticulate)`? I thought that package was required to run python in R sessions

Comment: Yup, it's loaded in the set up chunk, which seems to be sufficient because the code inside the other chunks successfully generates an output. It's just the actual code that doesn't display. Also it seems that calling the a `{python} ... {}` chunk is enough to for Rmarkdown to know to run reticulate even if it hasn't been explicitly loaded.